# Creating an "illegal import" list in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

Is it possible to create a list of "illegal imports" (classes/packages I don't want people to use) in IntelliJ? I browsed through the settings but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing available is the "Illegal package dependencies" inspection. Search for "Illegal package dependencies" in Settings | Inspections and then press "Configure dependency rules" to configure.

Comment: I didn't have time to try your solution earlier and sadly that's not what I am looking for. This inspection allows me to prohibit creating dependencies between classes/packages in my projects but what I need is a way to prohibit users from using some libraries (or parts of them). I've got a Checkstyle rule verifying that but many people forget to run it before commiting and only get a failed Jenkins build later. It's a quite large waste of time.

Comment: This inspection allows you to prohibit code in your project from depending on any code that you want, even if that is not part of your project. The [scope language](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/scope-language-syntax-reference.html) allows you to match any package, even if code in that package is part of a library.

Comment: The page you've linked helped a lot, "Illegal package dependencies" work like a charm!